# HDD Sata vs usb

Tags: linux, media, file-transfer, transfer, hard-drive

Ok I have a couple external HDD that I put into my home made media server. One is a 3tb seagate external HDD and for some reason when I have it connected by the USB adapter it has transfer rates of 25mb/s or more. However when its connected directly to the motherboard like all my other HDD I only get about 15-24 kb/s. As you can guess this is a problem because it just took me 3 days to transfer a folder that should have taken a couple of minutes. I have tried looking in forums all over but have not found anything that could explain this. If anyone has an idea as to how I could fix this or why this is I would be very grateful.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

SATA cable can at times drive you nuts, try connecting to another sata port, try changing the cable. [Why is my hard drive so slow? Is this normal?](https://superuser.com/questions/562630/why-is-my-hard-drive-so-slow-is-this-normal) this link can be helpful for various tests on SATA drives.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Answer (score 0):

updating bios may help, some motherboards aren't compatible with hdds > 2TB